# Efficiently convert big rar file to multiple bzip2

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, compression

**The situtation:**

I received a big rar file containing multiple log files.
I am converting each individual log file to a bzip2 archive.

**What i am doing now:**

Decompress the rar file completly, and only then convert all log files to bzip2 archives.

**What i would like to do:**

Be as efficient as possible by not storing all the uncompressed files first.

My first idea is to parse the output of unrar to distinguish when a file has been fully uncompressed, and then start a bzip2 compression on it.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since unrar supports a `p` command to print files, something like this should work:

```
for FN in $(unrar lb "$RARFILE"); do
   unrar p -ierr "$RARFILE" "$FN" | bzip2 -c > "$FN.bz2"
done
```

If the archive is a "solid" archive this will not be very efficient since it will have to process all the files multiple times. Also be careful if your file names can contain spaces.